# Can you use the product Septic Shock (tm) in water to use on trees to help soil break down

Tags: fruit-trees, citrus

I have bought Septic Shock from the store for bacteria in septic tank. Ok, but I want to use it two tablespoonfuls in gallon of water to put around fruit trees. Dp you think this will work  to benefit soil for nutritional gain? Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, there is nothing beneficial to plants in this product, just bacteria and some enzymes. I cannot imagine how this can be good for your plants; it may, in fact, kill them. The enzymes and bacteria in the product should have no effect on the soil itself; it certainly shouldn't release any nutrients.

A general rule of thumb is to never apply soil amendments without a soil test confirming that your soil actually needs those amendments.